# Is there a non-hacky way to prevent bouncing on my webpages on iOS Safari?

Tags: web, safari, standards

It just so happens that on iOS 10.3 Safari (and may be even older versions too) the web pages bounce when scrolling ends. I do not want that fancy bouncing on my own website and the ones I visit. Much prefer just the standard scrolling behavior!

Is there a standard "non-hacky" way, i.e. without using javascript's `event.preventDefault()`, to stop Safari from doing this? Unable to find anything related to this on Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW1) site that *works*.